# Yii2: Custom Validation on Dates based on two models

Tags: php, yii2, customvalidator

I am having two models namely
`Patient Admission` having two columns such as `admission_date` and `discharge_date`
and another model `daily_ward_entry` having a date field say just `date` both models are related by `ipd_patient_id`

Now What I want is to  create one or two validators, so that I can restrict the date entry in `daily_ward_entry` **between** `admission_date` and `discharge_date`

I had a look at the `compare validator`, but I can't make out, how to replace the value to be compared with attribute from another model with relation.

I have tried following variations, but it always throwing error:

**Variation one**

```
[$this->discharge_date, 'compare', 'compareValue' => $this->admission_date, 
'operator' => '>='],
```

error - `Unknown Property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException`

**Variation two**

```
['discharge_date', 'compare', 'compareValue' => 'admission_date', 'operator' => '>='],
```

error - `Discharge Date must be greater than or equal to "admission_date".` This error is generated irrespective of date is lower or greater

**variation three**

```
[strtotime($this->discharge_date), 'compare', 'compareValue' =>
strtotime($this->admission_date), 'operator' => '>='],
```

error - `Unknown Property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException`

I need some direction and help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you have to perform custom validation. in Custom function you will get all model data in POST, so you can get data and perform validation.

Comment: Your answer is lacking in detail. Can you expand it to demonstrate what you mean?

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to achieve your validation rule using a [custom validator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#creating-validators):

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['daily_ward_entry', 'validateDate'],
    ]
}

public function validateDate($attribute, $params) {
    if(!($this->patientAdmission->admission_date <= $this->$attribute && $this->$attribute <= $this->patientAdmission->discharge_date)) {
        $this->addError($attribute, 'The Daily Ward Entry must be between the admission date and the discharge date.');
    }
}
```

Something like this should conceivably work, I am not entirely sure how your relations are set up so you'll likely have to modify that a little.